# Redshift adds 4/5 Hours to timestamp columns when copied using "COPY command" from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, parquet

I am trying to copy data (Parquet File) from S3 to Redshift using redshift's COPY Command.
The data is copied successfully but I see an additional 5 hours added to the timestamp field. When I try the same activity using Text Files , the data is moved correctly without the additional 5 hours.

Copy command functions fine if the s3 files is of type TEXT/CSV but not parquet.

copy schema.table_name from 'S3://

Expected result : 2019-01-18 00:00:00
Actual Result : 2019-10-18 05:00:00

Comment: Timezone issue.

Comment: It might be `timezone` issues, `IST` might be converting into `UTC` or `vice-versa`

Comment: what does the source data look like raw?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: wouldn't the behavior be same for both CSV and Parquet if it was a timezone issue ?  When I load a CSV file I see the correct data but only while loading a parquet file , I see the issue.

Comment: @JonScott : The source data is just a hive table created on S3. I have loaded the table using the current_date() function of hive.

Comment: Right - there is your problem i think. that is being written using your local timezone wheras copy command / redshift will be converting this to UTC.